# Bootstrap 5 classes not working for circle image and pill shaped buttons

Tags: html, css, image, button, flexbox

I added the bootstrap class to make image circle using the .rounded-circle class for image and for the buttons i tried using .rounded-pills class but nor is my picture becoming cirular and nor is button becoming pill shaped. i tried using the input tag too for the button but it isnt working.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row mt-2">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <img src="123.jpg" class="rounded-circle mt-2" width="204" height="118">
    <p class="p1">Sometext here <br/><span class="percent">90%</span> off <br/>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg button1 rounded-pill"> Order Now  <i class="bi bi-cart-fill i1"></i></button>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Button class and Ringing class both are working

Comment: yes the code was correct the issue was that i used bootstrap through downloading it and it didnt make this code work, but when i used cnd it worked. Any idea what could be the reason?